# Calculating data difference between server database and client (embedded) database

Tags: database, relational-database, data-synchronization

Let's have a classic server-side RDBMS (Oracle/MS SQL/MySQL) and a client side embedded database (e.g. sqlite). We want some tables kept in sync between client and server.

Each server-side table to sync has its counterpart in client-side with the same schema (...or at least similar considering the different data types supported by the database engines). Moreover each table has a timestamp column updated by every update operation.

How can we collect the rows that are updated either server or client side since the last sync efficiently? *Efficient* meaning

- with low bandwith usage, e.g. not sending entire tables back and forth
- in a resource friendly way so that the syncing process can be utilized frequently

Comment: Just store the timestamp of the last sync, select anything newer than that timestamp, and send that and the timestamp, then the server does the same witht he timestamp the client sent? Doesn't seem that difficult to figure out...

Comment: Yes, but you would never actually verify that you are in sync. You make a single failure in one of the sync processes and you are out of sync and you will never recover. I was thinking of a process that every time verifies that we are in sync (at least all timestamps are match up), but that seems to be overkill. Although doing that verification occasionally seems to be good compromise. Maybe it could be done by calculating a hash of the table data (primary keys and timestamps only) and then comparing the client and the server side hash value.

Comment: If the sync is transactional (all or nothing), I don't see how you could get out of sync unless you're violating your constraints, such as by changing your clock backwards.

Comment: It is a transaction but its highly distributed one. One example: a client who is online only occasionly syncs changed records with timestamp earlier than the LastSyncedTimestamp for other clients. You will not sync that changes for all other clients. Do you overwrite the LastSyncedTimestamp for other clients or the timestamp in the synced records or...?

Comment: I did not pick up on there being multiple clients. Even so, you're not storing a LastSyncedTimestamp. You need to store for each record a LastModifiedTimestamp. The above scheme (as long as each individual sync is transactional and all the clocks are relatively synchronized) then works fine.